# Display the amount of ERC-20 token to be spent on a function call

Tags: solidity, erc-20, metamask

I am relatively new to Solidity programming, although I have a strong basis in procedural and OOP programming.
I have a small ERC-20 token which I am developing for fun. The contract contains a function which requires 1 input parameter (uint256 amount of tokens). When using Remix to call this function, Metamask pops up and asks for confirmation, but unlike the Transfer(to, amount) function, I don't get to see how much of my ERC-20 tokens I will spend.
Is there a way to make the Metamask wallet display the amount to be spent, from my code, without calling the Transfer function from my custom function?

To further elaborate just in case someone didn't get the question, when I send my ERC-20 to a friend, from Remix, Metamask pops up and displays the amount of ERC-20 token which I typed into the Remix  UI. This way, I know exactly how much I am going to send. But with this other function, it does not. I wanna change that.

Comment: I am using BSC at this moment, would it make a difference? I verified my code on BscScan, the same thing which would be necessary for EtherScan.

Comment: It is better to ask Metamask developers. I'd guess that they have to deploy that contract in BSC.